# How to set up MongoDB to be read-only for non-localhost connections

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB instance on my EC2 server that I want to be accessible both from the machine itself (on localhost) and also remotely.

I currently have it configured so that I can connect to my db from the machine itself on localhost:27017 (with read/write access). I want to make this db available (but only readonly) to other clients via my.ip.address:27017.

How would I go about setting this up?

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on [authentication](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication) as well as adding an local user with both read and write permissions you can also add a read-only user.

You would have to manage the authentication in your application / shell code but basically, anyone not from local host should authenticate as the read only user.